# Prevent light-locker from setting volume to 100%

Tags: sound, xfce, lightdm, lock-screen, volume-control

I'm on 14.04 with XFCE.

When I lock the screen it appears to mute the system volume (or perhaps just mute anything from the locked session?).

When I log back in the volume is reset to 100%. This hurts my ears!

How can I stop light-locker doing this?

Comment: I have the same problem. If you are the only user, you might want to disable lightlocker and use another locking mechanism such as i3lock. After you have disabled lightlocker, create a shell script  `/usr/local/bin/xflock4` and have it run `i3lock`.

Answer (score 0):

On xubuntu 16.04 the way it comes it appears to close running apps. Not that it mutes anything but shuts it down completely. I don't know if 14.04 xfce includes the session and startup gui that 16.04 has or not, but on 16.04 there is a box to check to save session automatically though. I think it might use a different locker to, as mine uses one called **LightDM GTK+ Greeter Settings**

Anyways this link shows the box for 16.04 that I think would keep your settings, session in general.[Session and startup gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvyb.png) Might be different in 14, but you may be able to find it and install it in the software gui. I'd imagine there is a setting like this somewhere if you don't have this gui.